# Proper CSS to frame image with images for top left and bottom right corner

Tags: css

I'm working on a concept of using an image that isn't a perfect square and using it at the top left and bottom right of the image, but I want to position it so it's 25px off the image slider.

What is the proper way to position this to look like the mock-up?

Positioning using `position:relative; and top/left: -XXpx;` I think this is best way but I could be wrong

Positioning using `margin-left: -XXpx;` etc Don't think this is right at all

Position using `vertical-align` I was unsuccessful at getting this to work

[Here is a fiddle of it - Stripped Down](http://jsfiddle.net/stillb4llin/zFa99/2/)

[image: Image of what site looks like]   --  [image: Mock-up in Photoshop]

Comment: You are not trying to make usable web design using one of those WYSIWYG editors, are you?

Comment: No, I made all of this in PS, and this is my first attempt at just creating something that I mocked up.  I usually code on the fly.  I use notepad ++ for my editing.

Comment: I doubt you will succeed using just float and no script. Might be worth a try using the pseudo selectors ":before" and ":after".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your first approach is the best: http://jsfiddle.net/zFa99/8/

You want to put `position: relative` on the container which holds the main image and the two corner images, and then position the corner-images absolutely.

```
#slider { position: relative; }
.tl-corner, .br-corner { position: absolute; }
.tl-corner { bottom: 0; right: 0; } /* this line is not ncessary as top:0 and left:0 are default */
.br-corner { bottom: 0; right: 0; }
```

There is no need to float the corner images.

Comment: Thanks.  I removed the floating, and you are correct.  I appreciate it.